# How to loop through Lua table using key, value, and index

Tags: arrays, loops, lua, iterator, iteration

I want to loop through a table that looks like this

```
function add(t, k, v, ...)
    if k ~= nil then
        t[k] = v
        t[#t+1] = k
        return add(t, ...)
    end
    return t
end

my_table = add({ }, "a", 5, "b", 4, "c", 3)

for i,k in ipairs(my_table) do
    local v = my_table[k]
    print(k, v)
end
```

Result:

> a - 5
>
> b - 4
>
> c - 3

But I want to be able to loop through the table using the index, the key, and the value, so it looks like this:

> 1 - a - 5
>
> 2 - b - 4
>
> 3 - c - 3

Is this possible in Lua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterator:

```
function triples(t)   
  local function next_triple(tbl, idx)
    idx = idx + 1
    local k = tbl[idx]
    if k ~= nil then 
      return idx, k, tbl[k]
    end
  end
  return next_triple, t, 0
end
```

Usage:

```
local a = {"q", "w", "e", q = 11, w = 22, e = 33}
for i, k, v in triples(a) do
  print(i, k, v)
end
```

Output:

```
1   q   11
2   w   22
3   e   33
```

Comment: you could also use `ipairs` and `print(i,v,a[v])`

Comment: @Piglet - Yes. I don't know why OP don't like his own code.

Answer (score 2):

An  alternate implementation of Egor's `triples` function using coroutines:

```
function triples(t)
  return coroutine.wrap(function()
    for i, k in ipairs(t) do
      coroutine.yield(i, k, t[k])
    end
  end)
end
```